# session/forms authentication timeout

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to get my site to go back to the login page after a certain amount of time if there is no activity from the user.

In my web.config so far I've tried:

```
 <system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/notifications.aspx" loginUrl="~/index.aspx" timeout="1" slidingExpiration="true">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="2"/>
</system.web>
```

but when I try to load a page after a few minutes, I'm getting an error due to a session variable not being present -

Shouldn't this go to the login page if I was to try anything?

Any deas?

Thanks,

Comment: http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/12/caution-with-using-sessiontimeout-and.html

Comment: What if you set your values higher? Using 1 and 2 minutes may be a bad test case.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to test if the Session variable still exists? Session["Something"] != null

Comment: Yeah i think this is the way I'll have to go..check if session is not nothing